# Probability about balls and urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics

#### $b$ balls are randomly placed in $b$ urns. What is the probability that exactly one urn is empty?

---

I started studying Probability yesterday and a few doubts came out:

**a)** should I consider balls and urns equal among themselves?

- equal urns, different balls;
- equal urns, equal balls;
- different urns, different balls;
- different urns, equal balls.

**b)** if I consider the order of extraction, will the result be the same on each case of item **a**?

*Note*: could someone, show me the result for each one of the possible cases of item **a**, please?

Thank you.

Comment: BTW, book's answer is $\frac { b!{ C }_{ b }^{ 2 } }{ { b }^{ b } }$ = b!/b^b * C(b,2).

Comment: Yes, randomly. About identical balls and urns, I don't know. It seems that the book considered different balls and different urns. Please, read item **a**.

Comment: Well, actually urns' size isn't a problem, in my opinion. You may suppose that any urn can contain all the balls and that's obviously what the problem suggests, once b^b is the amount of possible combinations.

Comment: @David: if there were such considerations as the size or the ball, surely the answer would be more complex! Perhaps here "different" means distinguishable, i.e. we count "1 ball per urn" as $b!$ combinations, and it would be just $1$ combilation if the balls were not distinguishable.

Comment: @David: added this assumption to my answer!

Comment: That's exactely why I wrote items **a** and **b**. Those 4 cases give enough information to answer each one.

Comment: @Fëanor: if you like my answer and have no further questions, could you upvote it and "tick" it? :)

Comment: The problem is incompletely specified, since "randomly placed" could have many meanings. However, I think the **defualt** meaning is as follows. For each of the balls, we choose in turn an urn for the ball to go to, with all urn choices equally likely, and with independence among the various balls. Then there are $b^b$ equally likely possibilities. Whether balls or urns are distinguishable or not is irrelevant to the probability calculation. Imagine the balls all look the same, but have ID numbers in invisible ink.

Answer (score 1):

*We assume that the balls and the urns are identical.*

Obviously, $b^b$ is the number of combinations of putting "different" (distinguishable) balls in "different" urns.

So what we need to prove is that the number of the ways one can put the balls so that exactly one urn is empty is $b!*b*(b-1)/2$. This is easy. Indeed, the number of ways of putting exactly one distinguishable ball in in each urn is $b!$ Then, to get $0$ balls in one urn and $2$ balls in another, we need to take one ball from an urn and put it into another; there are $b*(b-1)$ ways to do it. We have done doublecounting, since we distinguish both urns and balls, hence the division by $2$.

Comment: I cannot follow the 'obvious' part: why $b^b$ is the number of putting different balls in different urns? Thanks!

Comment: You can put the first ball in any of $b$ urns, $b$ possibilities. You can put the second one in any of $b$ urns, $b$ possibilities for the second one, $b^2$ in total. And so on. We have $b$ balls, since $b^b$

Comment: You said that balls and urns are identical; so why did you consider one ball distinguishable?

Comment: It seems that the question itself is not clear enough!

Comment: @LeeKM: I think the question is in the title, and the body of the question is Fëanor's attempt to understand how to solve such problems. It does appear Fëanor has not fully mastered it yet, but I would congratulate him/her for the effort, and help, not downvote...

Comment: @Fëanor: am I correct in guessing that a).-d). were added by you, they are not from the text book?

Comment: @Fëanor: on "identical" versus "distinguishable": there is no contradiction here. We have attributed numbers to both urns and balls, but the result does not depend on the way we have numbered them. The more rigorous proof would require the concept of conditional expectation: $E[\text{some event given balls and urns}] = E[E[\text{some event given balls and urns|numbering of balls and urns}]]$

Comment: The outer expectation of the right hand side is the expectation "over" different ways to  number balls and urns. But the inner expectation, computed above, does not depend on how we number them... Thus it all equals to $E[\text{some event given balls and urns|any given numbering of balls and urns}]$